# Trigger confirmation message box during asp.net LoggingIn event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, authentication

I have a web application in vb in which I am using [this approach](http://geekswithblogs.net/Frez/archive/2010/05/17/preventing-a-user-from-having-multiple-concurrent-sessions.aspx) to prevent a user from having concurrent logins due to a simple licensing agreement.

It works great, if a user logs in with an account that is already in use, the first user gets logged out.  I am trying to add a messagebox or some kind of js confirmation box in the loggingin event that states:

```
This user account has been active in the last 20 minutes.
If someone else is using it, then logging in may possibly
compromise any report generation or activity.
Continue login?
```

---

Here is the code:

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server"  DestinationPageUrl="~/Dashboard/Default.aspx" >
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td align="right"><p><asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label></p></td>
                <td align="right">
                    <p><asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" Width="220" autocomplete="on" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" Text="*"
                        ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="Login1" /></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right"><p><asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label></p></td>
                <td align="right">
                    <p><asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="220"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" Text="*"
                        ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="Login1" /></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color: red"><asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" colspan="2"><asp:LinkButton CssClass="prettyButton" ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" ValidationGroup="Login1"  /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>
```

---

```
Private Sub Login1_LoggingIn(sender As Object, e As LoginCancelEventArgs) Handles Login1.LoggingIn

        Dim messagetext As String = "This user account has been active in the last 20 minutes." + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine
        messagetext += "If someone else is using it, then logging in may possibly" + Environment.NewLine
        messagetext += "compromise any report generation or activity." + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine
        messagetext += "Continue login?"

        Dim userNameTextBox As System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox = DirectCast(Login1.FindControl("UserName"), System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)
        Dim currentUser As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(userNameTextBox.Text)

        If currentUser IsNot Nothing Then
            If currentUser.IsOnline Then

             '*****CONFIRMATION MESSAGE BOX TO GO HERE*****/
             Dim result = MessageBox.Show(messagetext , "Login Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)

             '* IF USER DECIDES NOT TO LOGIN:*/
             If result = DialogResult.No Then
                e.Cancel = True
             End If

             '* ELSE LOGIN CONTINUES AND ORIGINAL USER IS LOGGED OUT*/
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Login1_LoggedIn(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Login1.LoggedIn
        Dim userNameTextBox As System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox = DirectCast(Login1.FindControl("UserName"), System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)
        SingleSessionPreparation.CreateAndStoreSessionToken(userNameTextBox.Text)
    End Sub
```

---

Now, I can use a windows form `msgbox()` locally, and everything works great, but once I put it on a server, the message box obviously doesn't work.  I've tried `ClientScript` and `ScriptManager`, but the client side check doesn't seem to get triggered.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the VB `MessageBox` in a web site. It will ONLY show up on the server - and will more than likely kill your page every time. The end user will never see it on his browser.

There are a bunch of ways you could handle what you're trying to achieve, though one that will work well is to show the user a `javascript` `confirm` box; which is more or less the same as a message box but has an `OK` and `Cancel` button instead.

You can show this to the user by injecting a little javascript to your page as it renders. So, remove your  `Dim result....` line and replace it with something like this: - this will inject some javascript to your pages HTML.

```
Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript
cs.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "userChecker", "UserCheck(Confirm('yourMessage'));", True)
```

**NOTE** - you will also remove the code that checks your dialog, I.E `If result = ....`

When the page loads the `confirm` dialog will appear. The captured response, in this case, will be passed to a `javascript` function called `UserCheck` - so have a `javascript` function in your HTML to accept it. Something like this:

```
function UserCheck(t){

    if (t){
       // do something for OK
    }else{
      // do something for CANCEL

}
```

Within the `UserCheck` you can easily handle the users response. Perhaps by redirecting, or causing a postback by calling the `__doPostBack` function of .Net.

Comment: Thanks. You know, I'm not able to get any `javascript` to work in the `Login1_LoggingIn` unless I set `e.Cancel = True`, thus cancelling the login.

Is it possible to reverse that in the UserCheck function?

Comment: I actually came up with a different approach, as this was taking me too long.  Thanks for the advice though!